# Handling foreign keys in T-SQL select stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing stored procedures to get data based on a given id and that's all well and good, but some of the columns are foreign keys and what I need are their values. How do I do all of this within a stored procedure?

For reference, I will be using ASP.NET (haven't learned it yet) to call these stored procedures and update the website.

For instance, in the AdventureWorks database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLoadProduct
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        [ProductID], [Name],
        [ProductCategoryID], [ProductModelID]
    FROM 
        [SalesLT].[Product]
END
```

[Screenshot of current SP result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ciJ.jpg)

What I want is for the last two columns to return the actual category and model names, not the foreign keys. Is the standard practice to do it all in one stored procedure as I am trying to do?

Comment: google `SQL Server Joins` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am misinterpreting your question, but you can include joins in stored procedures.

Example if you have where afkey links out to table 2

```
Table_1:                      Table_2:
id  name   afkey              akey otherinfo
1   fred   1                   1     info
2   jon    2                   2     other
3   abbie  3                   3     more info
```

If you want to display the otherinfo column instead of the afkey foreign key

You could have:

```
create PROCEDURE spLoad
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT NAME, OTHERINFO
        FROM TABLE_1
        INNER JOIN TABLE_2 
        ON TABLE_1.afkey = TABLE_2.akey
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN to join the parent table to the child tables.  In this case, the child tables are ProductCategory, and ProductModel.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLoadProduct 
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        p.ProductID
        , p.Name
        , p.ProductCategoryID
        , p.ProductModelID
        , ProductCategoryName = pc.Name
        , ProductModelName = pm.Name
    FROM 
        SalesLT.Product p
        INNER JOIN SalesLT.ProductCategory pc ON p.ProductCategoryID = pc.ProductCategoryID
        INNER JOIN SalesLT.ProductModel pm ON p.ProductModelID = pm.ProductModelID;

END
```

Inner join tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp